# Percentage formula that skips over blank weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an excel spreadsheet I have data that looks like:

[image]

Basically column A has the dates from the beginning of the year to the end of the year then Column B I manually enter values every Monday-Friday, Column C to get -2.3% I used the formula "=(C2727-C2726)/C2726" where 2727 and 2726 have the values 134,655 and 137,849 respectively. Then lastly column D has the days of the week.

The problem I have is that my current formula I have to enter every day because Monday and Tuesday get messed up because Saturday and Sunday are always blanks. So what I would like is a dynamic formula that does the same thing but for Monday it does "(Monday-Friday)/Monday" and Tuesday it does "=(Tuesday-Monday)/Monday"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have asked 8 questions and only 2 have been marked as answered. In some questions, you never comment or follow-up with the people who take the time to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do in Column C:

```
= CHOOSE( MIN( 3, MOD( WEEKDAY( A5 ) - 1, 6 ) + 1),
          "",
          ( B2-B5 ) / B2,
          ( B5-B4 ) / B5
         )
```

and copy it down, where Column B contains your values and Column A contains your dates.

[image]

Note, however, that you will need to handle the first cell that ends up referencing your titles or start of data. Look at cell B4 in the above example: it errors out because it tries to calculate with B1 which contains a title.  You may want to wrap this in an IFERROR:

```
= IFERROR( CHOOSE( MIN( 3, MOD( WEEKDAY( A4 ) - 1, 6 ) + 1),
                   "",
                   ( B1-B4 ) / B1,
                   ( B4-B3 ) / B4
                  ),
           "n/a" )
```